# Excel VBA 2007 Performance Issue on Windows 7 (64 Bit)

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I have written a VBA code in Microsoft Excel 2007 to send a SOAP Message and Handle the soap Response.
I am reading the Soap Response and writing values to Excel cells in a loop. 
The sample soap response is :-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getMyResponse xmlns:ns2="http://my.samplenamesapce/">
        <return>
            <col1>col1Value</col1>
            <col2>col2Value</col2>
            <col3>3.283E7</col3>
        </return>
        <return>
            <col1>col1Value</col1>
            <col2>col2Value</col2>            
        </return>       
      </ns2:getMyResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the VBA code to write response in cells is:

```
Private Sub getReportBtn_Click()
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Worksheets("my_report")
Dim request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim url As String
Dim response As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim requestData As String
    'Clear the Report Sheet
    WS.Range("A2:C65536").ClearContents
    url = Range("url").Value
    'Construct SOAP REQUEST
    request.Open "POST", url, False
    request.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
    request.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", ""
    'Create SOAP REQUEST BODY
    requestData = xmlBody
    request.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(requestData)
    On Error GoTo err_handler:

    'Send SOAP REQUEST  
    request.send requestData
    'Read SOAP RESPONSE
    response.LoadXML request.responseText

    Dim MyReport As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim MyReportList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set MyReportList = response.getElementsByTagName("return")
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For Each MyReport In MyReportList
        i = i + 1
        WS.Range("col1Range").Cells(i).Value =  MyReport.selectSingleNode("col1").Text
        WS.Range("col2Range").Cells(i).Value =  MyReport.selectSingleNode("col2").Text
        If MyReport.SelectNodes("col3").Length > 0 Then
        WS.Range("col3Range").Cells(i).Value =  MyReport.selectSingleNode("col3").Text
        End If
    Next MyReport
    If i = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data found for requested query!"
        Sheets("query").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If   
Sheets("my_report").Select
Exit Sub

err_handler:
    MsgBox "Error occurred during submission, please check your settings."
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

When I run My excel sheet on Windows 7(64 Bit), it is taking double amount of time as compared to running it on Windows XP (32 Bit) to process same data.
The configuration and physical location of both the machines are identical except the Operating system.

Comment: Are they both Excel 32 bit or is it 64 bit on Windows 7? It could explain the performance difference (although why I don't know exactly)

Comment: @nick-perkins Both are Excel 2007 (32 Bit).

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to declare the variables as 32-bit variables. To see if the variable declaration is the area of delay, set timers at the start and end of the code and a third timer before your WS.range clearContents. My hunch is that assigning memory space is taking twice the time on the 64-bit machine.